# After program running the 3D OBJ file model looks like collapsed while open in others are fine Why?

Tags: 3d, rendering, mesh

If you look at the images, it looks that the 3D model is collapsed glass broken kind.

What is the problem here?

[image]

It is screenshot after running a program. It looks that is broken or collapsed while the 3D model looks completely fine. Having to said that the lepsoid updated in original of 3D obj by the program.

[image]

It is screenshot after running a program from inside. It looks that is broken or collapsed while the 3D model looks completely fine. Having to said that the lepsoid updated in original of 3D obj by the program.